# Setting VENV for Flask app where to create my files

Tags: python, flask, python-venv

Asking this question here because I can't find any good answers to my question.

This video has confused me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0gcAh-cRvw

Codecademy is saying to create your app.py files directly inside the venv (virtual environment) folder. While other StackOverflow sources are saying to create your app.py and any other files and folders which are yours outside the venv folder. Even Flask documentation is somewhat hinting for me to create my files and folders outside the venv folder as they are saying [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/installation/#activate-the-environment) with `. .venv/bin/activate`

Therefore what is the correct way of doing it create my own files and folders outside the venv folder or inside it?

If I create my own files and folders outside the .venv folder then the folders inside the venv is none of my concern right apart from lib folder where I download new dependencies? But if I should create my own files and folders inside the venv folder then what should I do with the include folder? Can I put static css files inside the Include folder then?

Comment: You don't put your project's code into a venv. You *may* put your venv into your project folder, or anywhere else you like to have it.

Comment: @KlausD. So the youtube video is misleading? Because looks like the guy ``cd`` into his ``venv folder`` then started to create his ``app.py`` file inside his ``venv folder`` which he had named ``myapp``

Comment: I'm not going to watch it, but if you are asking if videos on Youtube can be wrong: the answer it: yes.

Comment: The include folder is specific to the venv... Flask uses its own project structure, such as a templates and static directory, and is unrelated to the venv folder layout.